# TinyTest against onUse DB

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Assuming they aren't, is there some way to make `meteor test-packages ./` use the same DB as `meteor`? I'd like to add some package tests that rely on user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `meteor run`, `meteor test-packages` takes into account the `MONGO_URL` setting.

Thus,

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb meteor test packages ./
```

will use the specified database.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Works great with ` mongod --dbpath .meteor/local/db`. Would've liked not having to start a seperate instance of mongod and supply MONGO_URL but it's great to have it working.

Comment: @eee3: well, for any serious app, you'll want to have a separate Mongo instance instead of the local one that Meteor spawns. Since you're already writing tests, looks like you're on the way towards a serious app.